# Не могу запустить проект в Intelij Idea

Tags: java, intellij-idea, запуск

Нету зеленого значка запуска рядом с кодом. Я переустанавливал не помогло. JDK скачивал.

[image]

Comment: Переименуйте Main -> main. Методы пишутся с маленькой буквы, классы с большой.

Comment: Если ответ верный, то Вы можете отметить его как правильный. См. справку: [Что делать с ответами на мой вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 3):

**Во-первых:**

Негоже называть классы с маленькой буквы.
Неуважительно это.

**Во-вторых:**

Название метода - опять мимо
Оно должно быть с маленькой буквы.
Как вам и сказали в комментариях.
Это точка входа в приложение.
IDE пытается найти метод `public static void main(String...){}` и когда находит, автоматически настраивает конфигурацию для запуска твоего приложения.
У тебя его нет.
IDE его не находит и не добавляет кнопку запуска соответственно.
Исправь это!

Тем более в Java есть свои code conventions, в которых явно описано как именно должен оформляться код
И там говорят, что класс должен начинаться с заглавной буквы, а метод с маленькой.

**В-третьих:**

Нет кнопки запуска...это страшно конечно, но поправимо.

Запускать приложение можно по-разному.

- Это может быть веб-приложение
- мобильное приложение
- консольное приложение
- плагин для той же идеи
- или что-то еще

И все это запускается по-разному.
И IDE далеко на всегда знает что именно ты от нее хочешь.

**Как это исправить?**

В том, месте где раньше у тебя была кнопка запуска, сейчас красуется следующая надпись:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Она как бы подсказывает, что нужно настроить параметры запуска приложения.
Для этого есть конфигурации запуска
Смело жми на кнопку Add Configuration

Появится следующее окошко

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В нем у тебя ничего не будет.
Ищи плюсик слева и жми на него

В появившемся, маленьком окошке выбираем пункт Application
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В окне появится форма настройки конфигурации запуска
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В поле Name указываем название конфигурации запуска

Далее находим поле Main Class и кликаем на кнопку справа от него
Появится следующее окошко для выбора основного класса, имеющего точку входа
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Выбираем класс и жмакаем OK.

После чего сохраняем конфигурацию запуска, нажимая на кнопку Apply.
После чего закрываем форму нажимая на кнопку ОК.

И вот она
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Заветная кнопка запуска приложения

Comment: Спасибо большое.Только начал изучать программирования.Очень помогли