# IDE(CodeRunner 4) не компилирует код

Tags: java, ide

Пытался сделать проект, но  не  получилось, решил удалить файлы с расширением java b class, и после этого перестали  работать любые коды на  java, на c++ работают. Переустанавливал IDE, исправлял в CleanMyMac права доступа(иногда помогает), обновлял MacOC, всё  бесполезно[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот скрины из IntelliJ IDEA
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

При попытке запустить
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Идея от вас просто хочет чтобы вы сконфигурировали условия запуска

Comment: я вот тут описывал конфигурацию запуска: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1219930/189027

Comment: хотя вам для начала нужно еще указать JDK для вашего проекта

Comment: добавил дополнительное фото, где ничего не получается

Comment: у меня сейчас не так много времени есть чтобы в битву экстрасенсов играть, если хотите - можете написать мне в ТГ(он указан в профиле) и там по УД могу быстро сказать куда тыкать и что делать. Предложение бесплатное. И по времени ограниченное)

Comment: вопрос можно удалить, наверное, чтобы других участников не смущать

Comment: Можно просто добавить ответ. Я  проверил, реально из-за кириллицы в пути файла

Comment: Да, можно и ответ добавить) Если хотите, то можете сами его добавить (через 3-е суток по-моему его сможете отметить как верный)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что в пути к файлу имелись русские названия папок. Достаточно было переименовать папки на английский язык